# How to clone a record into a new record with new ID

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, clone

I wanted to be able to have a button that would create a new record (new ID number) with the same data that was in the record I chose to create a new one off of. So a user wouldn't have to re-type all of the data in if they would like to change one thing.

So essentially I want to be able to clone a item into a new record.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

In the past, I just used a manually initiated workflow that would copy the list item into the same list as a new item. This suited the need pretty well. Easy, straight forward.

Comment: are you talking about going into editing list mode, and copying the entire line of data into a new line?

Comment: No, a workflow could be triggered from the ribbon or the ECB that then copies the line data to a new line.

Comment: Anyone have a idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via CSOM or JSOM or SSOM. Below is an example using JSOM

```
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
var web = context.get_web();
context.load(web);
var oList = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Copy');
context.load(oList);
var selectedItems = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(context);

var currentItem = source.getItemById(selectedItems[i].id);
context.load(currentItem);
context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this,CreateNewItem),Function.createDelegate(this,error));

function CreateNewItem(sender, args){
    var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
    var oListItem = oList.addItem(itemCreateInfo);
    oListItem.set_item('Title', currentItem.get_item('Title'));
    oListItem.update();
    oList.update();
}
```

Comment: how do I use jsom? I never tried this..

Comment: You can do this using a Script Editor WebPart. It is basically client side code.

Comment: so add a new web part (script editor) in my view form and copy the above code into it?

Comment: Yes you can add the web part in your form. This code won't work straight away. You need to add a HTML button tag and then hook up the click event. Then get the current item id and then use that to get the item by id etc.

Comment: anyone can assist please?